# How to have an AI controlled GameObject naively avoid another one?

Tags: unity

I have an idea of an AI controlled game which the gameobject will follow a path but it will change its path if I put another gameobject in front of it. For instance, if the moving game object is moving horizontally, and I put a static game object on its path, I want it to turn and continue its progression vertically just before it hits it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use raycasting. From the GameObject, cast a ray to `transform.forward` with a specific avoidance range. When raycast hits an object, save the original target, turn either `transform.right` or `transform.left` and continue moving.

From now on, start casting another ray in the direction of obstacle we are avoiding. Continue moving forward until the second raycast hits nothing, then rotate `GameObject` to original target again.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, the existence of the second object (regardless of location) changes the direction of the first object?  If that's the case, and there are only two options (move this way without the object, this other way with), then create a bool on the controller of the first object, and either send a message from the second object to set the bool to true on the first object (which would be read by the controller), or have the first object constantly check for the existence of the second object (potentially easier, but much less efficient).